# Building successfully, yet gives warnings that referenced components cannot be found

Tags: .net, wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, compiler-warnings

When I build my project I keep getting warnings that various referenced components could not be found in multiple projects, however it does say that the build was successful. If I remove/readd the references then the warnings will go away for one compile, but then they come right back on the next compile.

I just moved this project into Visual Studio 2012 (from 2010) and that's one of two problems I'm having, the second being a bit more frustrating... when I press F5 to debug Visual Studio changes modes (i.e. the toolbar changes so you can see it's gone into debug mode) but the application never launches and no breakpoints get hit.  My Application Resources section contains an AppBootstrapper object and my breakpoint is at the start of the constructor for the AppBootstrapper.

I'm not sure whether these two problems are even related or not.

EDIT: Any time I make a change and then press Ctl-Shift-B it builds without any warnings, however when I hit Ctl-Shift-B again the warnings come back and remain for each build I do until I make another change at which point the warnings go away again for a single build.

EDIT: I got the latter problem fixed.  I had modified my app.xaml to put my resources directly under the `<Application.Resources>` tag rather than nested in `<ResourceDictionary><ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries><ResourceDictionary>` tags when someone suggested I do so, but I guess it turns out it needs to be that way after all although I don't understand why... I just know that it doesn't actually try to create instances of the resources if it isn't don't this way.

I still have the other problem though which is a huge annoyance but at least stuff is running now.

Comment: The first problem may have relations to 32bit/64bit builds or not compatilbe .net versions. For the second problem, after starting the program (debugging) press the pause button on vs toolbar and see what the program is doing.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn It displays the "No Sources Available" "The call stack contains only external code" messages.  As I mentioned it doesn't even get into the constructor of the first resource I have so there's really no code it could be getting to that I could look at.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project's settings.
Probably there are set to the .net Client Profile.

- right click project
- properties
- Application
- Target Framework

Select any thing other then Client profile.
When you reference external dll's this settings won't work in most cases

Comment: I wish I could say that were it :(  All projects reference 4.5 (and not client), and all the components I'm getting the warnings for are project references.

Comment: do you reference them from a comon lib folder, or maybe pick them up from one of your own bin/debug folders?

Comment: If you use resharper it tends to pick up it's references from other debug folders instead of the your main dll library

Comment: It's just compiling to the default debug folder locations within each project folder and references are all project references.  Also, I don't have resharper (wish I did) or any similar tool.  Just PostSharp, but I don't think it could be causing this.

Comment: if you can provide this as an example i could download i'll take a look.

Comment: I fixed the one issue (see my edit), and it turns out the other issue is actually bug in VS 2012 (see link in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the warnings are a bug in Visual Studio 2012 when it does parallel builds.  Changing "maximum number of parallel builds" to 1 will make the error go away, but other than doing that there's no way to get rid of the warnings.  Microsoft is supposed to be including a fix for this in the second update for VS 2012 which is currently in the CTP stage:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759434/vs2012-parallel-build-produces-many-the-referenced-component-could-not-be-found-warnings

Comment: Thnx for the solution, i'll keep this in mind when i made the step to VS2012 :)